# unable to call javascript function using this operator

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

why this operator is not working with this javascript object

```
var data = {
    opt: null,

    ajaxCall: function () {
        //my ajax call code here

        this.fillDataInDiv(); //This statement is not working
        data.fillDataInDiv(); //this is working why ?
    },

    fillDataInDiv: function () {
        //code to fill data in div
    }
}
```

can someone explain, what is the difference between these two statement

1. `this.fillDataInDiv();  // and why this statement is not working`
2. `data.fillDataInDiv();`

Comment: Put [`console.log(this);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) just before using it, you'll find out...

Comment: how is `ajaxCall` invoked

Comment: can u explain the difference between those two statement ?

Comment: who is calling `ajaxCall`? is it added as a ajax callback? show us how is `ajaxCall` used

Comment: `this` is bound to the `ajaxCall`, I guess.

Comment: I am using data.ajaxCall() from some other method

Comment: take a look at this http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/the-basics-of-object-oriented-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

The `data` above behaves more like a namespace, not an object.

Consider this :

```
var data = function() {};

var dataObject = new data();
```

Now if you have to add methods to this class:

```
var data = function() {

    // Equivalent to public members

    this.opt = null;

    // Equivalent to public methods :

    this.ajaxCall = function () {    
        this.fillDataInDiv(); 
    };

    this.fillDataInDiv = function () {
        //code to fill data in div
    };
}
```

Comment: i m facing this issue when i use ajax call before the function

Answer (score 0):

This is depending on the way the `ajaxCall` be called.

For simple, it depends on the **caller**.

If you use `data.ajaxCall();`, then yes, `this` refers to the `data`.

But if the caller is not `data`, then `this` refers the caller but not the `data`.

For example:

```
var func = data.ajaxCall;
func(); // this inside data.ajaxCall refers to the window object.
```